# PHP MySQL search with LIKE wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, search

I had below query to search keywords in multiple fields (title, address, area), but the query doesn't came out any result, what is the proper way to perform multiple field search with the 'format' below?

```
SELECT * FROM `houses` WHERE `status`='open'
AND (
   `title` LIKE '%Grand Villas, LAS Street 8800, CA%' OR 
   `address` LIKE '%Grand Villas, LAS Street 8800, CA%' OR 
   `area` LIKE '%Grand Villas, LAS Street 8800, CA%'
)
ORDER BY `title`
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: You realise that `LIKE` will match text that contains some (or no) text to replace the `%`, it doesnt allow partial matches of the text between the `%`

Comment: i think the query was okay. check your db if there is really Grand Villas, LAS Street 8800, CA, exactly. but yes the use of % is not by comparing to an exact value. or try 'title' == 'Grand Villas, LAS Street 8800, CA'